# Spock script not compiling automatically in Spring MVC project which is using Eclipse IDE

Tags: eclipse, spring, groovy, compilation, spock

I am working on a Spring based web project (Eclipse as IDE), in which we want to introduce integration testing framework using Spock.  This project is based on Maven.  For this purpose I have installed Greclipse plugin and converted the existing project to groovy nature.  Also configured Maven to run the test classes in src/test/groovy folder, and everything working fine and all the spock tests are running fine with run "Maven test" phase.  Configured the build path to compile the groovy test files to target/test-classes.

The problem is coming when I run the Spock tests using Run -> Run configuration.  It runs file with Junit runner using run configuration, it is picking up the compiled test class from target/test-classes.  Whenever I modify the Spock test script file, it is not automatically generating the classes, Run with Run Configuration is always picking up the old compiled class.

How to force the script to compile so that I don't always need to Maven clean and Maven test, to force it compile and run.

I have found in some other threads talking about modifying the Groovy compiler options to "Enable script folder Support", both checking and unchecking is of no use either.  Its not forcing the Spock script to compile (also tried enabling the same option in Eclipse Preferences global Groovy compiler option)

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Spock tests are implemented as a class extending `Specification`. So they are treated like any other Groovy class.

If in Eclipse under "Project" → "Build Automatically" is enabled, Eclipse compiles the classes automatically on every change. So if you change a Spock test in Eclipse, running it should always use the newest compiled version.

For automatic compilation to work correctly, the source has to be configured properly in Eclipse. Check via "Configure Build Path..." on your Eclipse project that under the "Source" tab the `src/test/groovy/` folder is configured correctly.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  Build is Automatically set to run on the project.  And also src/test/groovy/folder is added tot the source path in Project Properties.  But still it I am not seeing the compiled class files.  Is there anything still missing?

Comment: I found the problem and fixed it.  The project I am referring to does not have the Javabuilder setup in .proejct file.  As we were doing the build using Maven, I was not able to catch it.  Once I added the Javabuilder, eclipse was able to compile it every time I modify the file.